# Can I change leaderboards to friends only?

Tags: just-cause-3

There are random people in my leaderboards, I'm not interested about how random people are doing though. I just want to see the scores of my friends, is there any way to filter the leaderboards to friends only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn the global leaderboards off by turning extended leaderboards off in the gameplay options, this is enabled by default. If you disable it, you will only see the scores of your friends.

There will still be some popups of random people beating your score though, but I assume that's a bug that will hopefully be fixed.